# Bootstrap 5 Navbar with columns .. dropdown menu on right jumpy

Tags: bootstrap-4, flexbox, bootstrap-5

I am trying a navbar with Bootstrap 5 beta 1.

Here is the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
  <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Logo</a>
  <div class="col" style="background-color: grey;">column 1</div>
  <div class="col" style="background-color: red;">column 2</div>
  <div class="col" style="background-color: green;">column 3</div>
  <div class="col" style="background-color: purple; border:1px solid yellow">column 4</div>

  <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto" style="background-color: green;">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle dropdown-menu-left" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I am having an issue with the dropdown menu, where when I click it to open, the whohe navbar expands instead on just the dropdown menu opening.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
        <title>Static Template</title>
        <!-- CSS only -->
        <link
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
        <!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
        <script
          src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
          integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
            <button
              class="navbar-toggler"
              type="button"
              data-bs-toggle="collapse"
              data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
              aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
              aria-expanded="false"
              aria-label="Toggle navigation"
            >
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 w-100">
                <li class="nav-item flex-fill">
                  <a
                    class="nav-link active"
                    style="background-color: grey;"
                    aria-current="page"
                    href="#"
                    >Column 1</a
                  >
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item flex-fill">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="background-color: red;"
                    >Column 2</a
                  >
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item flex-fill">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="background-color: green;"
                    >Column 3</a
                  >
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item flex-fill">
                  <a
                    class="nav-link"
                    href="#"
                    style="background-color: purple; border: 1px solid yellow;"
                    >Column 4</a
                  >
                </li>
                <li
                  class="nav-item dropdown flex-fill"
                  style="background-color: green;"
                >
                  <a
                    class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                    href="#"
                    id="navbarDropdown"
                    role="button"
                    data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                  >
                    Dropdown
                  </a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
                    <li>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Now dropdown is working as well as columns are also spanning through the row as in yours case. I have used **flex-fill** class to span columns, or you can use `flex-grow:1` to achieve same. But set display flex and some width on parent before applying flex-grow on child elements.

Comment: On mine I was using columns so that the different sections would evenly expain. In your's the menu works but the coloured sections are not evently expanding

Comment: I've added a screenshot on the layout on mine

Comment: Thanks for adding screenshot. Check the updated solution. Might be this will work for you.